# Laravel - Change cookies directory from root to other

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-4

I have an application on Laravel 4.2. Currently, when I see the http requests sent from my application, the cookies are all stored in the root directory as `path=/`. I would like to store the cookies in a custom directory like another folder inside the storage directory.

Comment: Laravel store cache and session files inside 'storage/framework/' when you configure it to do so. And the only built-in `server-side cookies` are sessions in Laravel afaik. You should be using something custom for these cookies. Can you please share some details with us?

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN sorry the laravel version is 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Go to config/session.php,

set
'path' => other directory path (route path)